# I WANT CALCULATE SUM IN EXCEL

Tags: excel, sum

I HAVE A QUESTION ABOUT SUM IN EXCEL:
I  have  many rows in excel.
I want  to calculate sum of each row in one formula
for example

```
A B C D E 
2 3 5 6 8  24
4 5 6 8 9  32
```

BUT do not USE  separate formula FOR EVER CALCULATION (FOR EXAMPLE `=sum A1:D1`)
 CAN I USE WITH  ONE FORMULA TO CALCULATE SUM OF EVERY  ROWS

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to manually enter the formula to calculate sum of every row.

In the first row you would input `=SUM(A1:D1)` (did you mean to include E1 as well?)

Then follow [the instructions here](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/867-excel-apply-formula-to-entire-column-row.html) to apply it the other rows